# Alternative for Twitter.sharedInstance().session()?.userName after deprecation on iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, session, twitter, twitter-fabric

I've been using `Twitter.sharedInstance().session()?.userName` to display a user's twitter address in a Label in iOS (in Swift). Now I notice we get the following deprecation warning:

> -[Twitter session] will soon be deprecated. It is
>   recommended that users use -[TWTRSessionStore session] or
>   -[TWTRSessionStore sessionForUserID:] if they are managing multiple users

I switched to the recommend way, and expected to find a `.userName` property around, but could not find one.

How are people going about swapping out `Twitter.sharedInstance().session()?.userName` going forwards?

Comment: Hi did you find a solution?

Comment: @mariam nope nothing yet.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will search about it.

Comment: "I decided to switch to the recommend way" - Would you mind sharing this code? I've tried [TWTRSessionStore session] but the session method doesn't even exist on that class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're still looking for the solution, here's one:

```
if let session = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session() {
    let client = TWTRAPIClient()
    client.loadUserWithID(session.userID) { (user, error) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            print("@\(user.screenName)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Ok so I was having a problem with this as well, and it seems like all of the newer changes (which are admittedly very poorly documented) are designed to allow for better control over multiple user sessions existing at the same time. I did some digging into the `TWTRSessionStore` class that they mention in the warning, and what I found is that although the concrete implementation of TWTRSessionStore doesn't have a `-session` property, it adheres to the the following protocols `<TWTRUserSessionStore, TWTRGuestSessionStore, TWTRSessionRefreshingStore>` and the `TWTRUserSessionStore` does have a `-session` property.

So, to sum up, this is how I log out:

```
NSString *userID = [[[[Twitter sharedInstance] sessionStore] session] userID];

if(userID){
    [[[Twitter sharedInstance] sessionStore] logOutUserID:userID];
}
```

I'm doing it in Objective-C, clearly, but the Swift version is very similar.

Comment: I can see that sessionStore has a session property; but as far as I can see the session property has no userName. As far as I can see @tadija answer is the way to go; it seems a lot of code just to get a user name but it does work and you get a bunch of other items in the user (which is the TWTRUser type)

Comment: @tadija's answer and my answer perform the exact same method calls, the only difference is that he makes the API call after obtaining the userID to get more info on the user (including the username), but that API call is unchanged since before the switch to the new sessionStore stuff.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift,

```
    if let userID = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.userID {
        Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.logOutUserID(userID)
    }
```